# write good code for hibernate performance

Tags: java, hibernate

I am facing some performace issue in my application. Especially while saving to and retrieving from the database.
My application is a standalone application. Not a webapplication. I am using hibernate for database  communication.
This application has not gone in production. This application will be used 50 people simultaneously.

Here is the below code which I have used for getting session. I suspect below is the code for getting slowness.

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    public Session getSession() {

        SessionFactory buildSessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = buildSessionFactory.openSession();
        return session;
    }

    public Transaction getTransaction() {
        return getSession().getTransaction();
    }

}
```

I am not sure how to write a good code for opening session.
Can anyone suggest how to refactor this code to a good code?

Answer (score 2):

Also, are the session getting closed, means once the thread has completed a process, are we closing the session.

There is no single statement answer for your question unless the code is observed, there are lot of attributes on which the performance of the system depends.

1.) `GC` - When and which algorithm being used.

2.) How many `session are getting opened`, are there any sessions which are left idle. Long running sessions should be avoided.

3.) Introducing `Caching mechanism` in the code, Hibernate 2nd Level cache, query caching

4.) How `big the objects` are getting retrieved from the database.

5.) How `many queries` are getting fired into DB.

Please refer [this](http://blog.jhades.org/performance-tuning-of-spring-hibernate-applications/), [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-performance-tuning)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the similar type of issue in past, the base culprit for this is your are creating the factory instance every time  when you are trying to get a transaction.

Please use the singleton pattern to create the SessionFactory object, means just create Session factory once and get all the session instance from that factory object, I am pretty sure you will not face the performance issue after this change

change Something like below-

```
static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory;

public static getSessionFactory() {
    if(buildSessionFactory==null) {
        buildSessionFactory = new          
        AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }
}

public Session getSession() {
    getSessionFactory();
    Session session = buildSessionFactory.openSession();
    return session;
}

public Transaction getTransaction() {
    return getSession().getTransaction();
}
```

It will solve your problem